# Changes for MultiPanel Tablet layout - how to reduce to one Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, tablet

I am working on a project which should be able to show Multi-Panel layouts for tablets.
Currently fragments are used, but still there are a lot of activities.

MultiPanel layouts require that there is only one parent activity, which handles all the fragments in the multi-panel. The problem is, there are various activities shown inside a part of the multipanel layout, but ideally one activity is allowed. All the activities are large and complex - they deal with bound services, with broadcasts, and other life cycle specific functions. Reducing the activities to one activity in the case means the project completely has to be redesigned.

Is there any idea to get a solution on this, without merging all the complex activities to one activity and putting the logic from the activities into the fragments? Has anybody encountered this problem so far?

Comment: I had something similar and eventually I converted the activities into fragments. I only had to change and re-link just a few methods

Comment: Yes, it ounds like a lot of work. There also has to be extra treatment for the actionbar and things line onSearchRequested...

Comment: you have to use RealView Switcher

check demo ....http://stackoverflow.com/a/12872466/1487822

Comment: @ParagGhetiya: No, it is not about a flipping view. It is about activities and fragments inside a MultiPanel Tablet layout.